# Changing parseInt to nextInt

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have some code that works fine and does what it is supposed to. Unfortunately, I am required to just use nextInt();. Anybody know how to do this?

The current input (from text file):

```
3

4

2 3 6 7

4 5 6 7

2 2 2 2
```

The current output:

```
Average score of each assignment:

Assignment #1 Average: 2.666666666

Assignment #2 Average: 3.333333333

Assignment #3 Average: 4.666666666

Assignment #4 Average: 5.333333333
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Scores {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the name of the file containing the scores?");
    String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
    Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    //TODO: read in the values for the number of students and number of assignments using the Scanner on the file
    //TODO: create a 2-D to store all the scores and read them all in using the Scanner on the file
    int rows = Integer.parseInt(fileScan.nextLine());
    int columns = Integer.parseInt(fileScan.nextLine());

    int [][] myArray = new int[rows][columns];
      while(fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
         for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
            String[] line = fileScan.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
            for (int j=0; j<line.length; j++) {
               myArray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(line[j]);
            }
         }
      }
    System.out.println("Array of scores:");
    //TODO: print the entire array, row by row, using Arrays.toString()
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myArray).replace("], ", "]\n").replace("[[", "[").replace("]]", "]"));

    System.out.println("Average score of each assignment:");
    //TODO: compute and print the average on each assignment
    double total=0;
    int assignment=1;
        for(int i=0;i<myArray[0].length;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<myArray.length;j++) {
                total+=myArray[j][i];          
            }
            System.out.println("Assignment #" + assignment++ + " Average = " + (total/3));
            total=0;
        }
    fileScan.close(); 
    keyboard.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use `hasNextInt()` to test if there is another in in your input and then use `nextInt()` to actually read it. Then you don't need to read and split the lines separately. The position in the array can be computed from the rows and columns and by counting the ints.

Comment: @Jannik sorry I'm not really understanding. So I change int rows and columns to fileScan.nextInt(); and then what do I change the "split" line and the parseInt in the for-loop to?

Comment: You know exactly how many values you expect because you know the number of rows and columns. Hence you can use a loop to read as many ints as you expect with `nextInt()`. The position where you need to put your ints in the array can be computed from the number of ints you have read already.

Comment: @Jannik So `String[] line = fileScan.nextInt();` and `myArray[i][j] = fileScan.nextInt(line[j]);`?

Comment: No, you ditch the inner loop completely and assign the result of `nextInt()` to `myArray` directly.

Comment: @Jannik when I do that I get a bunch of compiling errors. Sorry for not understanding. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Scores {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the name of the file containing the scores?");
    String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
    Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    //TODO: read in the values for the number of students and number of assignments using the Scanner on the file
    //TODO: create a 2-D to store all the scores and read them all in using the Scanner on the file
    int rows = fileScan.nextInt();
    int columns = fileScan.nextInt();

    int[][] myArray = new int[rows][columns];
    while (fileScan.hasNextLine()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                myArray[i][j] = fileScan.nextInt();
            }
            fileScan.nextLine();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Array of scores:");
    //TODO: print the entire array, row by row, using Arrays.toString()
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myArray).replace("], ", "]\n").replace("[[", "[").replace("]]", "]"));

    System.out.println("Average score of each assignment:");
    //TODO: compute and print the average on each assignment
    double total = 0;
    int assignment = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray[0].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++) {
            total += myArray[j][i];
        }
        System.out.println("Assignment #" + assignment++ + " Average = " + (total / 3));
        total = 0;
    }
    fileScan.close();
    keyboard.close();
}
}
```

Comment: I get compiling errors around the private int. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Would you mind editing your code so it is embedded in mine? Because maybe I'm trying it wrong but I still get errors

Comment: sure - don't forget to accept the answer if it is the correct one ;)

Comment: Thank you! How would you do this so it prints out the average if there is more than 3 rows? Because when I have a text file that has more than 3 rows, it still divides by 3.

Comment: change the "/ 3" to "/ rows".